# shared pointer vs make shared ros2

Tags: ros, shared-ptr, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the difference between make shared and shared pointer? Accompanied by relevant links/information about the two as a basis would help when explaining. When/why would one be chosen over the other?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382826/shared-pointer-vs-make-shared-ros2/) by [MustafaTatli](https://answers.ros.org/users/78194/mustafatatli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A shared pointer is the pointer to the object (e.g. `shared_ptr<Object>`) that your program will use. You have options between shared, unique, weak, and auto -- each have different semantics and uses in programs.

`make_shared` is simply the factory to create this shared pointer to your object. On construction, you could use `new` to allocate your memory of your new pointer object, but there are various reasons why you might not want to populate your shared pointer on construction. For instance if you have a shared pointer in your program as a class member that you want to populate only after you've configured your program since the object needs some of those parameters.

So `make_shared` is a convenient factory to populate your shared pointer by passing through the constructor arguments to `Object` and returning a `shared_ptr` which you're using to actually accomplish your intended task. `make_shared` returns a `shared_ptr`.

Ex.

```
shared_ptr<Object> obj_ptr;
... configurations ...
obj_ptr = make_shared<Object>(object_argument_1, object_argument_2, ...);
obj_ptr->getThing();
```

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2